# How do I remedy this type does not exist in type error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steam, virtual-reality

I need to get value from another script but I keep getting this error that says

> The type name 'head' does not exist in the type 'SteamVR_Camera'.

My code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.VR;

public class HMDHelper : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SteamVR_Camera.head.localPosition HMDLocalPos; //Error is thrown here.

    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("g"))
        {
            AutoRotate();
        }
    }

    void AutoRotate()
    {
        HMDLocalPos = InputTracking.GetLocalPosition(Head);
        Debug.Log(HMDLocalPos);
    }
}
```

What exactly do I have to do to fix error?

This is the script that I retrieved the other value (`HMDLocalPos`) from...

```
//========= Copyright 2014, Valve Corporation, All rights reserved. ===========
//
// Purpose: Adds SteamVR render support to existing camera objects
//
//=============================================================================

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;
using Valve.VR;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
public class SteamVR_Camera : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform _head;
    public Transform head { get { return _head; } }
    public Transform offset { get { return _head; } } // legacy
    public Transform origin { get { return _head.parent; } }

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform _ears;
    public Transform ears { get { return _ears; } }

    public Ray GetRay()
    {
        return new Ray(_head.position, _head.forward);
    }

    public bool wireframe = false;

    [SerializeField]
    private SteamVR_CameraFlip flip;

    #region Materials

    static public Material blitMaterial;

    // Using a single shared offscreen buffer to render the scene.  This needs to be larger
    // than the backbuffer to account for distortion correction.  The default resolution
    // gives us 1:1 sized pixels in the center of view, but quality can be adjusted up or
    // down using the following scale value to balance performance.
    static public float sceneResolutionScale = 1.0f;
    static private RenderTexture _sceneTexture;
    static public RenderTexture GetSceneTexture(bool hdr)
    {
        var vr = SteamVR.instance;
        if (vr == null)
            return null;

        int w = (int)(vr.sceneWidth * sceneResolutionScale);
        int h = (int)(vr.sceneHeight * sceneResolutionScale);
        int aa = QualitySettings.antiAliasing == 0 ? 1 : QualitySettings.antiAliasing;
        var format = hdr ? RenderTextureFormat.ARGBHalf : RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32;

        if (_sceneTexture != null)
        {
            if (_sceneTexture.width != w || _sceneTexture.height != h || _sceneTexture.antiAliasing != aa || _sceneTexture.format != format)
            {
                Debug.Log(string.Format("Recreating scene texture.. Old: {0}x{1} MSAA={2} [{3}] New: {4}x{5} MSAA={6} [{7}]",
                    _sceneTexture.width, _sceneTexture.height, _sceneTexture.antiAliasing, _sceneTexture.format, w, h, aa, format));
                Object.Destroy(_sceneTexture);
                _sceneTexture = null;
            }
        }

        if (_sceneTexture == null)
        {
            _sceneTexture = new RenderTexture(w, h, 0, format);
            _sceneTexture.antiAliasing = aa;

#if (UNITY_5_3 || UNITY_5_2 || UNITY_5_1 || UNITY_5_0)
            // OpenVR assumes floating point render targets are linear unless otherwise specified.
            var colorSpace = (hdr && QualitySettings.activeColorSpace == ColorSpace.Gamma) ? EColorSpace.Gamma : EColorSpace.Auto;
            SteamVR.Unity.SetColorSpace(colorSpace);
#endif
        }

        return _sceneTexture;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Enable / Disable

    void OnDisable()
    {
        SteamVR_Render.Remove(this);
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
#if !(UNITY_5_3 || UNITY_5_2 || UNITY_5_1 || UNITY_5_0)
        // Convert camera rig for native OpenVR integration.
        var t = transform;
        if (head != t)
        {
            Expand();

            t.parent = origin;

            while (head.childCount > 0)
                head.GetChild(0).parent = t;
            DestroyImmediate(head.gameObject);
            _head = t;
        }

        if (flip != null)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(flip);
            flip = null;
        }

        if (!SteamVR.usingNativeSupport)
        {
            enabled = false;
            return;
        }
#else
        // Bail if no hmd is connected
        var vr = SteamVR.instance;
        if (vr == null)
        {
            if (head != null)
            {
                head.GetComponent<SteamVR_GameView>().enabled = false;
                head.GetComponent<SteamVR_TrackedObject>().enabled = false;
            }

            if (flip != null)
                flip.enabled = false;

            enabled = false;
            return;
        }

        // Ensure rig is properly set up
        Expand();

        if (blitMaterial == null)
        {
            blitMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Custom/SteamVR_Blit"));
        }

        // Set remaining hmd specific settings
        var camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
        camera.fieldOfView = vr.fieldOfView;
        camera.aspect = vr.aspect;
        camera.eventMask = 0;           // disable mouse events
        camera.orthographic = false;    // force perspective
        camera.enabled = false;         // manually rendered by SteamVR_Render

        if (camera.actualRenderingPath != RenderingPath.Forward && QualitySettings.antiAliasing > 1)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("MSAA only supported in Forward rendering path. (disabling MSAA)");
            QualitySettings.antiAliasing = 0;
        }

        // Ensure game view camera hdr setting matches
        var headCam = head.GetComponent<Camera>();
        if (headCam != null)
        {
            headCam.hdr = camera.hdr;
            headCam.renderingPath = camera.renderingPath;
        }
#endif
        ears.GetComponent<SteamVR_Ears>().vrcam = this;
        SteamVR_Render.Add(this);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Functionality to ensure SteamVR_Camera component is always the last component on an object

    void Awake() { ForceLast(); }

    static Hashtable values;

    public void ForceLast()
    {
        if (values != null)
        {
            // Restore values on new instance
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in values)
            {
                var f = entry.Key as FieldInfo;
                f.SetValue(this, entry.Value);
            }
            values = null;
        }
        else
        {
            // Make sure it's the last component
            var components = GetComponents<Component>();

            // But first make sure there aren't any other SteamVR_Cameras on this object.
            for (int i = 0; i < components.Length; i++)
            {
                var c = components[i] as SteamVR_Camera;
                if (c != null && c != this)
                {
                    if (c.flip != null)
                        DestroyImmediate(c.flip);
                    DestroyImmediate(c);
                }
            }

            components = GetComponents<Component>();

#if !(UNITY_5_3 || UNITY_5_2 || UNITY_5_1 || UNITY_5_0)
            if (this != components[components.Length - 1])
            {
#else
            if (this != components[components.Length - 1] || flip == null)
            {
                if (flip == null)
                    flip = gameObject.AddComponent<SteamVR_CameraFlip>();
#endif
                // Store off values to be restored on new instance
                values = new Hashtable();
                var fields = GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
                foreach (var f in fields)
                    if (f.IsPublic || f.IsDefined(typeof(SerializeField), true))
                        values[f] = f.GetValue(this);

                var go = gameObject;
                DestroyImmediate(this);
                go.AddComponent<SteamVR_Camera>().ForceLast();
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Expand / Collapse object hierarchy

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    public bool isExpanded { get { return head != null && transform.parent == head; } }
#endif
    const string eyeSuffix = " (eye)";
    const string earsSuffix = " (ears)";
    const string headSuffix = " (head)";
    const string originSuffix = " (origin)";
    public string baseName { get { return name.EndsWith(eyeSuffix) ? name.Substring(0, name.Length - eyeSuffix.Length) : name; } }

    // Object hierarchy creation to make it easy to parent other objects appropriately,
    // otherwise this gets called on demand at runtime. Remaining initialization is
    // performed at startup, once the hmd has been identified.
    public void Expand()
    {
        var _origin = transform.parent;
        if (_origin == null)
        {
            _origin = new GameObject(name + originSuffix).transform;
            _origin.localPosition = transform.localPosition;
            _origin.localRotation = transform.localRotation;
            _origin.localScale = transform.localScale;
        }

        if (head == null)
        {
            _head = new GameObject(name + headSuffix, typeof(SteamVR_GameView), typeof(SteamVR_TrackedObject)).transform;
            head.parent = _origin;
            head.position = transform.position;
            head.rotation = transform.rotation;
            head.localScale = Vector3.one;
            head.tag = tag;

            var camera = head.GetComponent<Camera>();
            camera.clearFlags = CameraClearFlags.Nothing;
            camera.cullingMask = 0;
            camera.eventMask = 0;
            camera.orthographic = true;
            camera.orthographicSize = 1;
            camera.nearClipPlane = 0;
            camera.farClipPlane = 1;
            camera.useOcclusionCulling = false;
        }

        if (transform.parent != head)
        {
            transform.parent = head;
            transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
            transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

            while (transform.childCount > 0)
                transform.GetChild(0).parent = head;

            var guiLayer = GetComponent<GUILayer>();
            if (guiLayer != null)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(guiLayer);
                head.gameObject.AddComponent<GUILayer>();
            }

            var audioListener = GetComponent<AudioListener>();
            if (audioListener != null)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(audioListener);
                _ears = new GameObject(name + earsSuffix, typeof(SteamVR_Ears)).transform;
                ears.parent = _head;
                ears.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
                ears.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
                ears.localScale = Vector3.one;
            }
        }

        if (!name.EndsWith(eyeSuffix))
            name += eyeSuffix;
    }

    public void Collapse()
    {
        transform.parent = null;

        // Move children and components from head back to camera.
        while (head.childCount > 0)
            head.GetChild(0).parent = transform;

        var guiLayer = head.GetComponent<GUILayer>();
        if (guiLayer != null)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(guiLayer);
            gameObject.AddComponent<GUILayer>();
        }

        if (ears != null)
        {
            while (ears.childCount > 0)
                ears.GetChild(0).parent = transform;

            DestroyImmediate(ears.gameObject);
            _ears = null;

            gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(AudioListener));
        }

        if (origin != null)
        {
            // If we created the origin originally, destroy it now.
            if (origin.name.EndsWith(originSuffix))
            {
                // Reparent any children so we don't accidentally delete them.
                var _origin = origin;
                while (_origin.childCount > 0)
                    _origin.GetChild(0).parent = _origin.parent;

                DestroyImmediate(_origin.gameObject);
            }
            else
            {
                transform.parent = origin;
            }
        }

        DestroyImmediate(head.gameObject);
        _head = null;

        if (name.EndsWith(eyeSuffix))
            name = name.Substring(0, name.Length - eyeSuffix.Length);
    }

    #endregion

#if (UNITY_5_3 || UNITY_5_2 || UNITY_5_1 || UNITY_5_0)

    #region Render callbacks

    void OnPreRender()
    {
        if (flip)
            flip.enabled = (SteamVR_Render.Top() == this && SteamVR.instance.graphicsAPI == EGraphicsAPIConvention.API_DirectX);

        var headCam = head.GetComponent<Camera>();
        if (headCam != null)
            headCam.enabled = (SteamVR_Render.Top() == this);

        if (wireframe)
            GL.wireframe = true;
    }

    void OnPostRender()
    {
        if (wireframe)
            GL.wireframe = false;
    }

    void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture src, RenderTexture dest)
    {
        if (SteamVR_Render.Top() == this)
        {
            int eventID;
            if (SteamVR_Render.eye == EVREye.Eye_Left)
            {
                // Get gpu started on work early to avoid bubbles at the top of the frame.
                SteamVR_Utils.QueueEventOnRenderThread(SteamVR.Unity.k_nRenderEventID_Flush);

                eventID = SteamVR.Unity.k_nRenderEventID_SubmitL;
            }
            else
            {
                eventID = SteamVR.Unity.k_nRenderEventID_SubmitR;
            }

            // Queue up a call on the render thread to Submit our render target to the compositor.
            SteamVR_Utils.QueueEventOnRenderThread(eventID);
        }

        Graphics.SetRenderTarget(dest);
        SteamVR_Camera.blitMaterial.mainTexture = src;

        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadOrtho();
        SteamVR_Camera.blitMaterial.SetPass(0);
        GL.Begin(GL.QUADS);
        GL.TexCoord2(0.0f, 0.0f); GL.Vertex3(-1,  1, 0);
        GL.TexCoord2(1.0f, 0.0f); GL.Vertex3( 1,  1, 0);
        GL.TexCoord2(1.0f, 1.0f); GL.Vertex3( 1, -1, 0);
        GL.TexCoord2(0.0f, 1.0f); GL.Vertex3(-1, -1, 0);
        GL.End();
        GL.PopMatrix();

        Graphics.SetRenderTarget(null);
    }

    #endregion

#endif
}
```

How do I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type is wrong. Needs to be `Vector3`.

```
private Vector3 HMDLocalPos;

void Start()
{
    HDMLocalPos = SteamVR_Camera.head.localPosition;
}
```

Edit:
Replace the `HDMLocalPos` property with a reference to `SteamVR_Camera` and access it's properties like this:

```
public SteamVR_Camera steamCam;    // popuplate this via inspector or with a Find() (or similar)

void Start()
{
    // access like this
    steamCam.head.localPosition = something
}
```

I think this is what you want (to actually change the head.localPosition of the camera).

Comment: That sort of works but the "HMDLocalPos = SteamVR_Camera.head.localPosition;" portion throws says an object reference is required for a non-static field, method, or property.

Comment: That is because you don't have a reference to `SteamVR_Camera` in your `HDMHelper` and `SteamVR_Camera` is not static (or has a static property  (keyword singleton)). I'd suggest to replace the `HDMLocalPos` with a reference to `SteamVR_Camera` and just access it's properties then. I'll edit that in.

Comment: Well I finally got it working. Thank you SO MUCH for the help :D.

Comment: Glad I could help :)